# How to sign in any Azure Active Directory (AD) user to a Shared Native app which connector to Office 365 Sharepoint Online APIs

Tags: azure, sharepoint, oauth, active-directory, office365api

Is it possible to set up a single "Native app" which can be used by users on different Azure accounts/directories so they can get data from their Office 365 Sharepoint Online?

We can get this working using a "Web app" because in the Azure portal where you set this up it has the "Multi-tenanted" option which can be set to Yes - the notes for this support this:

> Designates whether users in external organizations are allowed to
>   grant your app access to data in their organization's directory. This
>   control affects only the ability to grant access. It does not affect
>   any access that has already been granted.

And some early testing suggests this does indeed work. *However* this implies using an Oauth secret which must be embedded in the app and the notes here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code

State (in relation to the app secret):

> ....It should not be used in a native app, because client_secrets
>   cannot be reliably stored on devices. It is required for web apps and
>   web APIs, which have the ability to store the client_secret securely
>   on the server side.

For native apps, the docs here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview

State:

> Native client registrations **are multi-tenant by default**. You don’t
>   need to take any action to make a native client application
>   registration multi-tenant.

Which suggests they should work in the way we desire - however when we test this with OAuth flow from an account not in the same Azure AD where the native app was setup we get the following after authenticating:

**AADSTS70001: Application with identifier 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' was not found in the directory YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY**

So it appears this does not work. At present the only way it seems to make this work is to create a Web app and embed the client ID and secret in the native application.

Has anybody had success with multi-tenant native apps or any ideas/feedback on what I am doing wrong or could try?

**UPDATE** I realised there were two things wrong here:
* You can actually click on the "Manifest" button in Azure and edit the raw JSON, updating the 'availableToOtherTenants' value to make it multi-tenant.
* I didn't have the scope=user_impersonation in the OAuth flow.

Now it seems we can create a native app which users in other orgs/tenants can authenticate with.

**UPDATE 2** OK so it turns out our app now works for some users but at least one is getting:

AADSTS65005: Invalid resource. The client has requested access to a resource which is not listed in the requested permissions in the client's application registration. Client app ID: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA. Resource value from request: https://XXX.YYYYYY.com. Resource app ID: ZZZZZZZZZZZ. List of valid resources from app registration: 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000, 00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000.\r\nTrace ID: KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK\r\nCorrelation ID: CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC

I can't see why it would work for one user but not another if both are in different tenant/Azure ADs to where the app is created.

Answer (score 0):

If you were developing an native app which access the multi-tenant web API which also developed by you, you can set the add the `clientId` of native app to the manifest of web app's manifest with `knownClientApplications` property. So that when other tenant's users access the multi-tenant web API, it will also register the native app to their tenant.

Refer the code sample below which demonstrates a Windows Store application calling a multi-tenant web API that is secured using Azure AD:

[active-directory-dotnet-webapi-multitenant-windows-store](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-multitenant-windows-store)

Comment: We are trying to create a native app/connector which we can distribute and anybody can use to connect to their own sharepoint 365 data (without the user having to set up their own OAuth app). See my update above but also interested if you think this is the right approach.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It seems that you were using the [Azure AD V2.0 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-compare)( use `scope` instead of `resource`). Here is the request which works for me `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={clientId}&redirect_uri={redirectUri}&prompt=login`. What's exact request you were using?

Comment: Hi - We aren't using the V2.0 endpoint. The auth URL you entered closely matches ours although we have a state parameter and prompt=consent. Do you know if including scope=user_impersonation has any effect? In my tests I didn't notice it making a difference.

Comment: The **scope=user_impersonation** shouldn't affect this. Both OAuth 2.0 and OpenID connect in Azure AD V1.0 endpoint, we need to use the `resource` parameter to acquire the access token. But since the app you were developing required the permission to Office 365 SharePoint online, please ensure that the end-users's tenant also have the subscription to that resource. Is the application identifier is the client id of your custom application or the SharePoint online resource?

Comment: The application ID is that of the Native App created in Azure AD. We use the resource={SHAREPOINT_URL} but only in the final step of OAuth converting the code to a token - it seems it makes no difference whether it is in the first URL which directs the user to the login page.

Comment: Are you able to login with the request like in my preview comments only use `rsponse_type`,`cli‌​ent_id`, `direct_uri`  and `prompt`? It should prompt the consent page if you sign-in the app in that tenant first time.

Comment: Hi @Fei - As per my comment above we aren't using the v2.0 endpoint but yes we are able to login only using response_type, client_id, redirect_uri and prompt. And as per my update to the original question after manually updating the availableToOtherTenants setting in the manifest we have made some progress. But now it only works for some users, and at least one is getting the AADSTS65005 error mentioned in some other posts. I will update original question with a note about this.

Comment: Also Fei - I just noticed on your original answer you mentioned 'access the multi-tenant web API which also developed by you' - not sure how important a detail this is but we are not trying to access a web API developed by us, we are trying to provide an app which accesses the Office 365 API Sharepoint Online API.

Comment: For the **AADSTS65005** error, you need to grant the resource in you request to the app when you register your app.